# Derived Date Column Ruby Rails Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently moving my application from rails 2 to rails 4 and have hit an issue with the following sql command

```
SELECT concat(right(fy_wk, 2), '/', left(fy_wk, 4)) weekno, fy_wk, ca.caldate wkstart, adddate(ca.caldate,6) wkend, monthname(ca.caldate) month
                              FROM calendar ca
                              WHERE weekday(ca.caldate) = 0 AND ca.caldate = date_add(curdate(),interval (weekday(curdate())*-1) day)
                              ORDER BY caldate
```

in my view I use the column wkend like this...

```
<td height=20><%= display_date_short(c.wkend.to_date) -%></td>
```

via the helper

```
def display_date_short(input_date)
  return input_date.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
end
```

This all worked fine under rails 2 but on rails 4 I get a no method error for the to_date on the view display. Obviously the field is not part of the table and created on the fly. It would appear it is being returned as a bigdecimal field and not a date.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Regards,

Peter

Comment: What does the error say? If it says `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_date' for nil:NilClass`, then c.wkend is nil

Comment: Which database is this running on?  And can you also post the schema for the calendar table?  Trying to determine why the `wkend` column values are being returned as `BigDecimal`.

Comment: The database is mysql version 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 and the table definition is -     CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `caldate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `workday` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'Y',
  `fy_month` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fy_wk` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2558 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: this is the error msg undefined method `to_date' for #<BigDecimal:7ff9e5f19ed8,'0.2016E4',9(18)>

Comment: 06/2016 201606 02/05/2016 00:00:00 08/05/2016 00:00:00 May this is what gets returned when running the query direct using toad